# Problem reinstalling Ubuntu on Amazon Deeplens

Tags: uefi, bios, amazon

I'm tryin to reinstall Ubuntu (18.04.2 LTS) on the Amazon Deeplens following [this pdf tutorial](https://s3.amazonaws.com/deeplens-public/factory-restore/DeepLens_System_Restore_Instruction.pdf).

However once I'm selecting the BOOTx64.EFI file in the Bios to boot from (step 2 from the pdf tutorial), I get the error message: "this file is blocked by the current security policy".

How do I proceed?

Comment: Try disable the secure boot in bios settings, if it helps.

Comment: Yeah I tried looking for something like it but there is no such setting to be found in the BIOS environment, is there somewhere else I can disable it?

Comment: I doubt that, it should be something in the bios. it's also possible their instructions to create a UEFI boot key are erroneous. Maybe try creating the key with different methods, such as using Rufus. Rufus has an option to create the key in UEFI mode which works reliably for me. other than that it has to be BIOS-side.

Comment: I also tried making the USB with Rufus but to no avail (still the same bios error). Here's some snaps of the BIOS: https://imgur.com/a/IegHv5n

The second photo is the "setup utility", as you can see there's no secure boot to disable here